# Using UIDeviceOrientation change notification instead of viewillTransistionToSize

Tags: ios

I have managed to support Portrait and Landscape orientations for my app.

However, my implementation is based on `UIDeviceOrientationChangeNotification`. I do not use `viewillTransistionToSize`

Offical Apple sample code for AlternateViews does use notification based approach. So I assumed it should be fine.

- Is there any significant advantage/disadvantage of using one over another?
- Would it ever happen that my app will not get `deviceOrientationChangenotification`?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a combination of both. But to me it looks like viewillTransistionToSize gives more control as you can execute code

- before rotation begins
- during rotation
- after rotation

while in case of Notification you only execute code after rotation.

Not sure but I found this thru experimentation and not thru docs.